# MacOS Animation delay in swift

Tags: swift, animation, nsanimationcontext

Is it possible to add a delay to an animation with Cocoa?
In my current code it shows a window and hides it with fade animation. What I am trying to do is add a delay before the fade animation.

```
   @IBAction func doIt(_ sender: NSButton) {
       openPanel()

       NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (cont) in
           cont.duration = 1.0
           self.panel.animator().alphaValue = 0
       }
       //hide on completion
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap what you want to delay in a DispathQueue async call:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { //delays 1 second
  //code to delay            
}
```